# Closure of open subsets of a locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $S$ be an open subset of $X$.
Is it always true that the closure of $S$ is contained in $X$?

Comment: Do you know how the closure is defined?

Comment: If $X$ is the topological space under consideration, surely all the relevant open sets and closed are subsets of $X$, so clearly the closure of $S$ must be contained in $X$ - or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure of an open subset $S$ is:
$$
\bigcap_{S\subseteq C, \text{ C closed}}C
$$
Each $C$ is the complement of something open in $X$, so is necessarily a subset of $X$. So this intersection is necessarily is a subset of $X$ as well.

*This is really a reiteration of what Old John said in the comments, with the supplementary definition of closure, (it was an unintended reiteration)*